# Can I adjust iPad display size to make it fit the screen better?

Tags: ios, ipad

I have an iPad mini (original model) running iOS 8.4
Recently I have noticed many apps seem to be too large for the screen; usually the top or bottom is partly off screen.

When I press the button, the home screen displays normally for a few seconds, then seems to "grow" e.g. the iPad in the top left now shows "Pad" wth the "i" off the screen.

This may have been since a software upgrade, but I can't be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you have somehow turned on the Zoom feature of Accessibility?

- Open the settings app
- tap general
- tap accessibility
- turn off zoom

If you need more details, the following article might help

https://www.apple.com/ios/accessibility-tips/

Answer (score 0):

Check Settings->General->Accessibility->Zoom and made sure that Zoom is unchecked. Other than that, as far as I know, there is no way to change anything like that, at least without Jailbreaking (and I strongly recommend against that). It does seem like the kind of thing that iOS 9 might fix, though.

Comment: Zoom and accessibility could easily have this effect  no jailbreak needed.

Comment: @bmike True, I completely forgot about that. Answer updated.